# Merging Data from four excel files into a single database file

Tags: database, talend

I have 4 excel files and I wanted to insert the data from these 4 excel files to a single database file in MSSQL.

```
1st Excel file - 10 rows 
2nd Excel file - 20 rows
3rd Excel file - 30 rows
4th Excel file - 40 rows
```

The table in MSSQL should have 100 rows after the task. Thw column names are similar in all the files.

I have taken

```
tfileInputExcel1 -> tMap -> tMSSQLOutput
tfileInputExcel2
tfileInputExcel3
tfileInputExcel4
```

All mapped to the same tMap.

**I just don´t know how to Map different input sources to a single tMap**. I have been searching on the internet on this but I haven¨t find any relevant for my need. Can anyone here help me out on how to map tMap to a multiple input and output sources.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:
tFileList (with the appropriate file mask)-tFileInputExcel-tMap-tMSSqlOutput

or if you want just one interaction with the database:

tFileList (with the appropriate file mask)-tFileInputExcel-tMap-tHashOutput
onSubJobOk
tHashInput-tMSSqlOutput

Note the tMap is necessary only if you have to transform the input data

Comment: How to map different input sources to a tMap? I need to take the data from 4 excel sheets and so

Comment: in the proposed design you get the files one after one, so you just have to map one file at a time, not 4.